# Trouble querying Redis vector store when using HuggingFaceEmbeddings in langchain

Tags: redis, huggingface-transformers, langchain, py-langchain

I'm trying to create an RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) system using langchain and Redis vector store. The langchain documentation provides an example of how to store and query data from Redis, which is shown below:

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores.redis import Redis
import os

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

metadata = [
    {
        "user": "john",
        "age": 18,
        "job": "engineer",
        "credit_score": "high",
    },
    {
        "user": "derrick",
        "age": 45,
        "job": "doctor",
        "credit_score": "low",
    },
    {
        "user": "nancy",
        "age": 94,
        "job": "doctor",
        "credit_score": "high",
    },
    {
        "user": "tyler",
        "age": 100,
        "job": "engineer",
        "credit_score": "high",
    },
    {
        "user": "joe",
        "age": 35,
        "job": "dentist",
        "credit_score": "medium",
    },
]
texts = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"]

rds = Redis.from_texts(
    texts,
    embeddings,
    metadatas=metadata,
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    index_name="users",
)

results = rds.similarity_search("foo")
```

This example uses **OpenAIEmbeddings**, and it works perfectly. However, when I opt for a different embedding method, such as

```
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2",
            model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'}
        )
```

I encounter an issue when trying to query the Redis vector store. I receive the following error for rds.similarity_search("foo"):

```
ResponseError: Error parsing vector similarity query: query vector blob size (1536) does not match index's expected size (6144).
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring and how to fix it. Has anyone else faced a similar problem or can provide guidance on resolving this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the issue is that you are trying to reuse the same index despite using two different embedding models.

I ran your code and if I change the embedding model and then provide a different name for the index, thus presumably creating a new one instead of reusing an existing one, everything works as expected.

If for some reason you want to use the same index with different embedding models, I think you would need to be more specific about the [vector schemas](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain_community.vectorstores.redis.base.Redis.html#langchain_community.vectorstores.redis.base.Redis) and/or modify the embedding vectors prior to saving them in the database. I did not try this myself though, so it is just speculation.

Note: When I was running the code I received a warning to use the embeddings implementation of langchain_community instead of the langchain one, as the latter seems to be deprecated. Perhaps doing this you would also receive other, potentially more meaningful, errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have resolved the issue by specifying the appropriate vector scheme, where the correct "dims" parameter is set to the required value for the used embedding type (in my case, it should be 6144)